# Homework problem on identifying a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I had this problem in my discrete math/modular arithmatic course where I had to find the first 10 terms of a series F(r), starting from F(3).

The given information is:

**F(3)=1

F(4)=13

F(10) %  (10^9+7)  is  719666144

F(r) is defined and exists for all values of r>=3**

Is it possible to solve such problems? How do we approach these? Is there anyway we can actually find the general term?

EDIT: One of my friends claimed he solved the complete problem fron this much data. I just wanted to check If there is someone that bright actually present or that he was just bragging.

The additional information is:

We define an **onto** function from $[n] \times [n]$ to $[n-2] \cup \{0\}$ as follows, where $[n] = \{1,2,3,\ldots ,n\}$,

$$f : [n] \times [n] \rightarrow [n-2] \cup \{0\}.$$

1) $f(x,x) = 0$.

2) $f(x,y) = f(y,x) > 0$, for $y ≠ x$.

3) $f(x,y) \leq \max\{f(x,z),f(z,y)\}$ for all $x,y,z$ belonging to $[n]$.

**F(r) is the number of ways in which f(x,y) can be defined for n=r.**

Comment: What's stopping you from setting $F(r) = 0$, $r \ne 3,4,10$? There have to be more conditions?

Comment: We just saw this one [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/418687/homework-problem-on-series) where it was closed as not a real question.

Comment: Based on my mind-reading skills, I believe [this](http://www.codechef.com/JUNE13/problems/SPMATRIX) might be the actual problem.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Great find!

Comment: This is a *sequence*. Not a series.

Comment: i dont think it has anything to do with matrices

Comment: The functions (in this question) and the matrices (in the coding problem I linked to) are equivalent just think of the $[x,y]$ element in the matrix as the value of the function $f(x,y)$.

Comment: @PeterKošinár yes similar. So any ideas on how he'd have gotten the answer without the entire question?

Comment: I request the administrator to kindly block/delete this question as this is from a contest on a programming site which is still going on.http://www.codechef.com/JUNE13/problems/SPMATRIX here is the link.Thankyou.

Comment: Flagging would have been the more appropriate thing to do ...

Answer (score 1):

Many here will tell you (correctly) that there are infinitely many choices.  Usually, if you are given finitely many terms, you are expected to find the "simplest" rule that results in those terms.  Nothing such stands out for these, which is why the other one was closed.